# Sass - can I target a label with for?

Tags: css, sass

With Sass can I target a label based on it's 'for' entry:

```
<label for="remember-me" class="right">Remember Me</label>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the normal CSS attribute selector.

```
label[for="remember-me"]
  color:red
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zfIBo

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just add in something to an already defined label selector, and do something special for your 'remember-me' field, you can also do this:

```
label {color:black;
    &[for="remember-me"] {color:red;}
}
```